# How to rearrange a 1D numpy array by a single value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have been googling all over, but I cannot find a simple numpy function to do this without slicing and concatenation. I want to rearrange a numpy array to allow the `0` in the `A array` given below to be put first and everything before that to be put last.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Using slicing and concatenation

```
idx_0 = (np.diff(A) < 0).argmax()+1

B1 = A[idx_0:]
B2 = A[:idx_0]

B = np.concatenate([B1, B2])
print(B) # np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Look up how to slice and concatenate arrays.  Any tutorial on the data type should teach you how to do this.

Comment: @Prune I want to do it without slicing and concatenation. I've edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: What's wrong with slicing and concatenation?

Comment: @hpaulj not sure if it is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Since everything in the original array has to be moved in one way or other, there isn't much you can do to save on copies.  Concatenating 2 slices is probably as good as you can do.  Or allocate a `empty` of the right size and assign the slices.  Feel free to do some time tests on the alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to rotate the array after finding the index of the initial zero. For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
zero_index = np.where(A==0)[0][0]

np.roll(A, -zero_index)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: But looking a `roll` code, I see that it creates a `result` array, and copies slices to it.  It may be convenient, but it is not more efficient that the alternatives.

Comment: @hpaulj do you think it's *less* efficient? If not, I think the readability is a small win. It seems like [there was a time when it was less efficient](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10848), but probably not any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives:

```
In [39]: A = np.array([2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [40]: np.roll(A,-3)
Out[40]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4])
In [41]: np.concatenate((A[3:],A[:3]))
Out[41]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4])
In [42]: res = np.empty_like(A)
    ...: res[:10]=A[3:]; res[10:]=A[:3]
    ...: res
Out[42]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4])
```

Some timings:

```
In [43]: timeit np.roll(A,-3)
29.7 µs ± 925 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [44]: timeit np.concatenate((A[3:],A[:3]))
3.64 µs ± 139 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: res = np.empty_like(A)
    ...: res[:10]=A[3:]; res[10:]=A[:3]
    ...: 
3.67 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`roll` is noticeably slower.  BUT, if a lot of time is spent in general setup, it might fare better (but never faster) with larger cases.

`roll` is doing a generalized version of my `res` assignment example.  Here that times about the same as `concatenate`.

===

For a much larger `A`

```
In [52]: A = np.arange(1000000)
In [53]: timeit np.roll(A,-3)
2.5 ms ± 76.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [54]: timeit np.concatenate((A[3:],A[:3]))
2.25 ms ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [55]: %%timeit
    ...: res = np.empty_like(A)
    ...: n = len(A)-3
    ...: res[:n]=A[3:]; res[n:]=A[:3]
    ...: 
    ...: 
2.49 ms ± 91.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Now `roll` is close to `res assign`, with a reletively small setup.  Concatenate is still a bit ahead.